# ErrorException(code: 0): Erroneous data format for unserializing 'MongoDB\\BSON\\ObjectId'

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-6

Frequently, getting the unserializing error from laravel core file `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:53` for Mongodb data.

Please find the running versions,

- php 7.4.
- laravel 6
- mongodb 7 (AWS Database)
- mongodb-1.6.1 (php extension)

Note: Currently doing the process of laravel upgrade from `v5` to `v6` and mongodb upgrade from `v3` to `v7`.

Error:
`Erroneous data format for unserializing 'MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId' {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Erroneous data format for unserializing 'MongoDB\\BSON\\ObjectId' at /home/forge/om-dev.objectlegal.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:53)`
[CallQueuedHandler.php:53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRXDQ.png)

Verified the doctrine version, currently using `"doctrine/orm": "^2.7"`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).